# Reset file associations to default (.z01 opens w/ winRar)

Tags: windows-8.1, file-association

Does anyone know how to set file associations back to default on windows 8. Currently the file extention "z01" is opening with "winRar" & i want to reset it back to "unknown program".

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to set a *specific* file type association is to *right*-click on a file of that type, select *Open with*, and *Choose default program...*.
[image: File context menu]. Unless you've *just* purchased the PC, resetting *all* file type associations to default might have undesirable consequences: many applications you've installed will no longer be correctly associated.

You can also use software such as NirSoft's [FileTypeMan](http://nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) to see what current associations are and adjust as desired.

Answer (score 0):

DrMoishe Pippik's method works if you want to change the file association for a program to another, however in your case if you want to associate it with *Unknown* (as it was at the start) then it's *slightly* more complicated:

1. Go to **Default Programs**.

[image]

2. Go to **Set Your Default Programs**

[image]

3. Since the program you don't want .z01 to associate with is WinRAR, go to WinRAR and click on **Choose Defaults for This Program**.

[image]

4. Now just uncheck the .z01 extension, **save** and exit!